# PHP Curl and API

Tags: php, json, api, curl

maybe this question was answered before but, I tested everything what i found on a web, and couldn't make it work...
I have to form this kind of request with PHP.

- curl ­X POST "https://page.com/login/CODE" \
- ­H "Accept: application/json, text/*;q=0.2" \
- H "Accept­Charset: utf­8" \
- ­H "Accept­Encoding: gzip, deflate" \
- d '{"appCode": "CODE"}' \
- --cacert cacert.pem \
- --compressed

Here is my php code:

```
$data = array('appCode'=>'CODE');
$data_json = json_encode($data);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL_REQUEST);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

If I get a correct answer from API it should be a JSON array, alse massage Login Error.

Got no Idea what is this text/*;q=0.2", any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

**If someone will need here the code that helped me:**

```
$data = array('appCode'=>'CODE');
$data_json = json_encode($data);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://login.com/CODE",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_json,
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('cache-control: no-cache'),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
   echo $response;
}
```

**Eventually i find out what was wrong.**

I got all the manual at pdf file.
I was copying header information from pdf and pasting it into
[Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) 
When I copy and paste header information like this 
**Content-Type: application/json**

On sublime it was shown normally with dash (-) but when i opened with other software like notepad++ it was showing without dash.
**ContentType: application/json**

That was the problem why my code didn't work :)

Comment: text/*;q=0.2" is called media type quality factor and is used for assign precedence to files, in this case plain text has precendence of 0.2 on scale 0 to 1

Comment: Could it be the reason why its not working?

Comment: no, you are not setting all options needed in your curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nice trick for such curl "translations"

You can download Postman [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) and than perform your request as usual one
 
More about Postman [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/). 
When you finished your request building, you can just go to Code(on right top corner, below Save) -> and select which language you prefer. In your case PHP Curl. After that you can just copy that code to your curl request.
 It will look like this:[image: curl example from Postman]


**EDIT:**
[image: cUrl]
And this is how it will look like if you select cUrl option in "Code".

Comment: The problem is I have to do it from my server because the access to API can only be done from server IP.

Comment: I've added Edit, so you can see how it looks like.

Comment: Thank You wery wery wery much :) god damn i got that array You my hero

Answer (score 0):

This option should be uncommented, if you need a POST request

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Comment: No not this one :) I was trying it already and comment it out. Thats not the case. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS this should send post header too...